# mysql query needing quotes around variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a local apache server and a mysql server. My local website works fine.

When I uploaded my website to ipage (host) and I imported the database to their mysql server I was able to connect to database but queries are returning null.

I checked the database that is uploaded the only difference I was able to see is that locally the type is innodb but somehow ipage does not support innodb and now the type became MyISam.

Now I did some tests:

this is my php code:

```
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['type']);                      

$sq1 = "SELECT 
      course_id, 
        FROM 
          courses 
        WHERE 
        training_field LIKE '$type'"
```

This works locally but not on remote server. Now when I hard code $type. i.e.

```
$sq1 = "SELECT 
      course_id, 
        FROM 
          courses 
        WHERE 
        training_field LIKE 'ENIGNEEING'"
```

This works everywhere?!

Any Idea

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: yes I you are correct I just ported mysql_real_escape_string to mysqli_real_escape_string and all other queries to MySQLi. still same issue

Comment: @Kam - Why not post the new code (append it please) to the question.

Comment: @Kam - may be due to 'ENIGNEEING' being spelt incorrectly and in the form you have typed it in correctly.

Comment: This is the new code :) and by the way, I just tried Prashant's suggestion and it works! I just don't get why at all.. :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sq1 = "SELECT 
  course_id, 
    FROM 
      courses 
    WHERE 
    training_field LIKE '".$type."'"
```

PHP concatenation :)

Comment: you can find the difference using echo $sq1;

Answer (score 1):

```
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['type']);                        

$sq1 = "SELECT course_id FROM courses WHERE training_field LIKE '$type'"
```

Try this